# Correct usage of HTML Semantic Elements

Tags: html, semantics

I was wondering what's the "best" or most common way to use semantic elements in HTML. I know what they are and what they do, but should I use them like that :

```
<section>
      <div class="info">
        ...
```

or like that :

```
<section class="info">
        ...
```

Is it wrong to use one or another ? Are both actually "valid" ?

Another example would be the header element :

```
<body>
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
        ...
```

or should I directly start with

```
<body>
    <header class="logo">
        ...
```

Maybe this question might sound strange for advanced developers but for a beginner it might not be obvious and I didn't really find a clear answer.

I'm personally using the "long" version and started questioning myself when I started looking at other people's codes.

Comment: Either way is valid, but  if you want to have semantic HTML, try to avoid using `<div>` and `<span>` since they do not have any explicit meaning. When you have to use `<div>` or `<span>` a descriptive class is sufficient. IMO less is more, having less clutter makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine. It comes to personal preferences.

The technical aspect is that it will add a bit of padding between two nested elements.

Answer (score 4):

Both are fine. but if i should read other people code i prefer code like this one.

```
<body>
<header class="logo">
```

To read second code,

```
<section>
  <div class="info">
    ...
```

you need to carefully scan for the class names, picking them out from between the  boilerplate.
And once you're a few levels deep in the markup, it becomes tricky to keep track of which  closing tags go with which <div...> opening tags

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to go with the first one as it seems more organized, but honestly, it just preferences.

```
<section>
  <div class="info">
    <h1>Information</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid. When using semantic HTML, the tag should be able to give you some context for what is happening. I prefer structuring my pages like this:

```html
<section class=blogPost>
<!-- section acts as a container for content -->
<h1>Introduction to HTML</h1>
<p> blah blah blah blah </p>
<!-- h1 and p are the actual content -->
</section>
```

You can use classes for each tag in your HTML file for increased semantics by using microformats, though semantic tags usually just mean you try to use specific tags instead of unspecified tags such as div or span.
I would say that you should try to limit the number of tags used if possible because adding a div tag just to give it a class will end up confusing you even more, especially if you can just put your content in your header or section tags directly.